Rendered image coming out black for compositing
Issue: I'm a beginner, trying donut tutorial ("Blender guru"). For compositing, when I render the image, there appears a black screen with many dots (from the start of render till the end), shown below.

Facts: I've connected the nodes in compositing workspace as shown in image. (I've restarted the app. a few times as well).

Observation:
When I render the image (by F12 key) from Layout or Shading workspace, it renders correctly. But in any other workspace, like Compositing, Modelling, etc. it comes out black (shown earlier).
Below is the rendered img. (which is how I want), when I render it from layout workspace.

I want to find out, what might be the reason, for the image rendering to not occur when I'm at compositing workspace.
Please suggest any possible solutions which you might believe.

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Ya sure, the file was around 200mb with packing, so I used google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kbgPCRogG27e-46a9F0JmyR9drCaBNZZ/view?usp=sharing

In the Scene panel, you have selected an object as camera, you need to select your camera instead:


Thanks, that solved it. I was just assigning local camera instead of Scene>>camera.
